# QML access properties of elements in list

Tags: qml, qqmlcomponent

I have a list of MapPolyline and I try to save dynamically added objects into this list. well It works but when I try to get the objects in list it does not work. it says `TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` Here is my code

```
property list<MapPolyline> lines

 var component;
 var sprite;
 component = Qt.createComponent("lineStringComponent.qml");
 sprite = component.createObject(window,{"id": "button1"});
 sprite.addCoordinate(QtPositioning.coordinate(currentgcppoint.lat, currentgcppoint.lon));
 sprite.addCoordinate(gcppoint);
 map.addMapItem(sprite)
 lines.push(sprite)
 gcps.push(currentgcppoint)
 console.log("Added:", lines[1])
 console.log("width:", lines[1].line.width)
```

Here is `lineStringComponent.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
MapPolyline {
    id:polyline
    line.width: 3
    line.color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
}
```

The consoles output is :

```
Added: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined
```

It seems it has a delay when it tries to create a new object. How can we overcome this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly you only add **1** element to `lines`, and than you try to retrieve the second element of `lines` with `line[1]`. This is obviously `undefined`.

Try to access the first element of `lines` with `line[0]`.
Indices of JS arrays start with `0` (as in most languages).

If there would be a delay with object creation, than you could not alter any of its properties, which you do (`sprite.addCoordinate(...)`)

Comment: wow, thanks very much it was my obvious mistake which I had not notice thanks very much